# Excel: Calculate IF column based on another IF column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to use Excel to create a scorecard for different companies to use. The product I create needs to be a finished product - when a company representative fills out certain information on their company, Excel should spit out an answer on their ranking.

In order to do this, I have created a three-step approach:

- The first column uses an IF statement to code their response (i.e. "Yes"=1, "No"=-1)
- The second column uses an IF statement to weight their coded response (i.e. if the answer was "Yes" then for this question, it should be weighted more heavily by *1.5),
- The third column tabulates all their responses to give them back a ranking (i.e. if answer falls between 1-3 points then they are "Leader").

But here's the rub:
How can I calculate an IF column off another IF column without copy and pasting the values? I've tried to base the IF statement on the second column on the response in the first column - which has been calculated with an IF statement.

by example, the first column reads E5 `= IF(C5="Yes",1,-1)` and then right now the second column reads F5 `= IF(E5=-1,E5*1.5,E5)`. But I get a *#VALUE* answer because I'm basing one IF column off another IF column. Since the finished scorecard shouldn't show the backend or require the respondent to copy and paste their answers to make them from formulas into values, I need to figure out a way to get from column 1 to column 2. Any ideas?

Comment: Any function can use the output of any other functions in excel (as far a data types are appropriate, which is the case now), also the formula you posted seems ok. Please debug your formula (formula tab - evaluate formula) and let us know where is the issue.

Comment: It works perfectly well for me. I do not know what you are getting wrong. The only thing i could spot was on the formula in F5. U missed the double quotes for -1.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. The problem is definitely not having one IF based on another. Please copy in your post exactly the formulas in those cells (that is, CTRL+C CTRL+V, don't write from your head). Also, long shot, but ensure "Automatic calculation" is enabled in Options.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of your IF logics are out (reversed).

Place all formula into one IF statement, as you seem to have only two states - Yes (1) and No (-1).

=IF(C5="Yes",1.5, -1)

That should be it?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate col 1, place the weight in col 2, put this in col 3.

`=(IF(C5="Yes"; "1"; "-1") * (IF(C5="Yes"; F5; "1")))`